# M1 mac process keeps autogenerating and locks my port

Tags: macos, process

I tried to run my express app with port 5000, and I found that some processes are already using it:

```
↳ lsof -i :5000
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ControlCe 1677 user   32u  IPv4 0x728ff8e52d51c6dd      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
ControlCe 1677 user   33u  IPv6 0x728ff8e51d98ec65      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

So I simply tried to kill them to unlock the port, but it won't work because once I run the kill (or sudo kill) command, the process with the new PID locks my 5000 port again.

```
↳ kill 1677
↳ lsof -i :5000
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ControlCe 2159 user   32u  IPv4 0x728ff8e52fd4dc1d      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
ControlCe 2159 user   33u  IPv6 0x728ff8e51d98d0e5      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

I killed the process 1677, and then a new process (with PID 2159) came out.
It has different PID and different Device. I already tried to restart my laptop but it was also not working. Has anyone with M1 or Intel Mac experienced a similar issue like this?

Edit: I think ControlCe means Control Center?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Turning off the `AirPlay Receiver` (listens on port 5000) fixed the issue for me:

Go to **System Preference** --> **Sharing** --> **uncheck off the `AirPlay Receiver`**

For more details:
https://utf9k.net/questions/macos-port-5000-monterey/

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same problem too. I think it's because of macOS Monterey (12.0). To fix it, run this command in a terminal:

```sh
pkill ControlCenter; nc -l 5000
```

...and then hit Ctrl+C a few seconds later.

What that will do, is it will kill the `ControlCenter` processes, and then it will start an empty netcat TCP server listening on the very port used by `ControlCenter`, i.e., 5000. That way, because `ControlCenter` automatically restarts when it's killed, it will allocate that port before `ControlCenter` starts, so that when it does start, it will find that its port is in use and it will die.